# Multiple scenes on different canvases

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to create two scenes on two different canvases. Is it possible in Three.js?

```
var scene1 = new THREE.Scene()
var scene2 = new THREE.Scene()
scene1.add(camera1)
scene2.add(camera2)
```

...

```
renderer.render(scene1, camera1)
renderer.render(scene2, camera2)
```

Will it work like that?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: No. But I'm thinking about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - it is totally possible, but the renderer-instance is always bound to the WebGLContext of the canvas. So you need to create create a renderer for every canvas you have. So this would be

```
renderer1.render(scene1, camera1);
renderer2.render(scene2, camera2);
```

(the other way around works as well: you can use multiple renderers to render the same scene with different cameras)

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS**

You can also render multiple scenes into different regions of the same canvas, using just one renderer. For this you need to setup a different viewport and scissor-test for every scene like this (based on https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_multiple_views)

```
// first, render scene normally:
camera.aspect = totalWidth / totalHeight;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
renderer.setViewport(0, 0, totalWidth, totalHeight);
renderer.setScissorTest(false);
renderer.render( scene1, camera1 );

// then, render the overlay
renderer.setViewport(left, bottom, width, height);
renderer.setScissor(left, bottom, width, height);
renderer.setScissorTest(true);
renderer.setClearColor(view.background);

camera.aspect = width / height;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
renderer.render( scene2, camera2 );
```

Comment: I have tried it with multiple renderers but I create and destroy a lot of canvas during user interaction with the app. And this causes to hit some kind of renderers limit. After some iterations it stops to create renderers to the new canvases. Then I thought about this one renderer approach but I don't know if it will work, I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: @PogromcaMotyli If you are generating and destroying canvases for user interaction you are not approaching the problem correctly.

Comment: In that case, depending on how you do it, you might need to take extra care to handle destroying of the renderer (especially calling `renderer.dispose()`) instances correctly.

Comment: Now I'm testing one renderer with multiple viewports approach.

Comment: @Marcs "generating and destroying canvases for user interaction you are not approaching the problem correctly" what you mean? I have to show a window in the game and then a window is destroyed and its content is out of date. I could hide this box rather than destroy it but its contents had to be cleaned. Is the idea is that instead of creating a new canvas should I clean it once created?

Comment: Yes I would clear/modify a canvas/render and not re-init it each time, it is inefficient. Canvas initialization should be an init operation, and your game should "live" inside a canvas for the whole user interaction.

Comment: Game "live" inside one canvas but I have other stuff to show on top of it inside window/box and it is also 3d. So I have to use another canvas. The problem is that not all windows/boxes have 3d contents and this 3d contents is always different. So I would keep scene, renderer, lights, camera and only add/delete some models to it. Then I could just add my renderer to new canvas every time when I need to show new window/box. Does it make sense?