# How can I get a single domElement canvas from each three.js scene?

Tags: canvas, three.js, rendering, scene

I know that threeJSrenderer.domElement returns the one and only HTMLCanvasElement of the renderer

but I need to get the canvas of each scene that I created in a single renderer so that I can use it in pixi for special purposes, since multiple renderers are not a good practice

any ideas?

Comment: You don't need multiple canvases. It's very bad for performance. You could just use one full-screen canvas and render each scene on a different part of the canvas. [See here for demo1](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_multiple_elements) and [here for demo2](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_multiple_elements_text)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple scenes on different canvases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442952/multiple-scenes-on-different-canvases)

Comment: no, but you are actually right, it's not possible. thanks!

Comment: https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-multiple-scenes.html